# Services Actions Missing in Central Admin

Tags: central-administration, spservices

We recently added a new SharePoint server to the farm and to my surprise the server is not showing any actions in The Page Manage Services on Server .Please see the attached screenshot for further details 
[image]

After Stopping SharePoint Foundation Web Application Service 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your screenshot, it looks like the main Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service is stuck on starting.  This will need to be resolved before services can be configured for the new server.

Comment: Hi Mike Thanks for the answer.I stopped the service using STSADM but i am still not seeing any actions to start/stop the service in central admin .Please see the updated screenshot above

Comment: @anil The service will need to successfully stay in a running state.  Go ahead and try and start the service again.  If it does not start, then remove the server from the farm, and rejoin it.  You can do this by running the configuration wizard again on that particular server.  Be sure you have the farm passphrase before attempting the changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that perhaps you need to start your Internet Explorer by right clicking the icon "Run as Administrator".

UAC can be a blocker as discussed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2010/07/10/missing-links-or-access-denied-in-central-admin-sharepoint-2010.aspx). Another possibilities within the scope of your problems can be:-

-- Add User to the Farm Administrator group.
 
 -- Add User as the
   computer administrator on every computer in the farm.  
-- Check if
   you are able list all services in powershell using "Get-SPServices"
   by the same logged in user as the one opening the Central Admin. 
--
   Check in the services.msc if SharePoint Timer service is started or
   not.
-- Check the ULS and Application Category of Windows event logs
   and see if something is out of place.